# Why is JAX shell not seeing the command that is on the global path?

Tags: osascript, javascript-automation

When I call my script that then calls my shell command I'm getting an error:

> Error: sh: excel: command not found

I'm using the following code in my SCPT file:

```
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
var test = app.doShellScript('excel');
```

When I run `excel` in Terminal it sees it just fine. Why is shell not finding the command?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a search path problem. It's opening a new Shell instance, and the environment variables, including search path settings, are not automatically exported.

```
(() => {

    // standardAdditions :: () -> Library Object
    const standardAdditions = () =>
        Object.assign(
            Application.currentApplication(), {
                includeStandardAdditions: true
            }
        );

    return standardAdditions().doShellScript('echo $PATH');
})()
```

Try the `echo $PATH` command both in .doShellScript and in the Terminal, and look for differing output.

Two options would be:

- Set the path that you want with a line like `export PATH=some/path/or/other:$PATH`, or just
- provide a full path to the app when you launch it.